# Counting array elements in Ruby (unexpected results by the count( ) function)

Tags: arrays, ruby, count, findall

In my understanding the following ruby expressions should produce the same result.
Apparently I am missing something, this is a way too serious bug to go unnoticed...

```
# returns the number of ALL elements in the array
count = @quotation.quotation_items.count { |x| x.placement == current_placement}

# Does what I expect
count = (@quotation.quotation_items.find_all { |x| x.placement == current_placement }).length
```

`quotation_items` above is an ActiveRecord `has_many` association

Answer (score 2):

#count does not take a block like that.

If you want to use conditions on a count, you would do:

```
@quotation.quotation_items.count(:conditions => "placement = #{current_placement}")
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count

Comment: it is CollectionAssociation method, not Calculation (see link)

Comment: The ActiveRecord count always triggers a SELECT COUNT(...) on the db - it is not the same as the Enumerable#count

Comment: Remember conditions should be expressed as `{ x: y }` or `['x=?', y]` and never `"x=#{y}"` since the last one is a potential SQL injection hole.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ActiveRecord you need to keep in mind that there's a point where it's compiling conditions and clauses for a query and a point where you have a result set. Certain things only work in one mode or the other, though it tries to keep things pretty consistent regardless.

In your case you are expecting `count` to work like Enumerable, but that's still a database-level operator.

To fix that:

```
@quotation.quotation_items.where(placement: current_placement).count
```

That composes a query that counts only the things you need, something approximating:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotation_items WHERE quotation_id=? AND placement=?
```

That's something that yields a single number and is considerably different than selecting every record, instantiating into models, then counting those using Enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of #count is incorrect.

I believe it doesn't accept a block. I'm not sure why it didn't return an error though.

you can use it like this :

`count = @quotation.quotation_items.map{ |x| x.placement == current_placement}.count(true)`